# Принцип работы HTTPS

Tags: алгоритм, https, шифрование

Не могу понять как работает HTTPS. В сети пишут, что https использует следующий алгоритм шифрования:

> Вы кладете предмет в коробку, вешаете замок от воров и посылаете
>   по почте. Адресат получает коробку, но не может ее открыть без ключа.
>   Тогда он вешает на коробку собственный замок и возвращает ее вам.
>   Получив свою коробку с двумя запертыми замками, вы убираете свой замок
>   (ее надежно защищает второй) и возвращаете коробку. В итоге адресату
>   приходит коробка, закрытая только на один – его – замок. Он снимает
>   замок и достает посылку.

Это готовый протокол какой-то?

`"Вешает замок"`.. как я понял, это шифрование неких данных... Получается: Алиса шифрует свое сообщение, отправляет его Бобу, тот шифрует пришедшее сообщение, потом обратно отправляет его Алисе, далее Алиса расшифровывает это сообщение... тут не понятно, разве ей удастся расшифровать??

Также не понятны сертификаты... Если используется симметричное шифрование, каким образом помогают сертификаты?

Comment: Какая то ерунда тут написана. Ключ сессии шифруется открытым ключом второй стороны, следовательно только вторая сторона, знающая свой закрытый ключ может расшифровать. Об этом даже в википедии написано https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL#.D0.90.D1.83.D1.82.D0.B5.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8

Comment: А сертификаты нужны для определения подлинности стороны (обычно сервера). А ассиметричное шифрование используется для обмена ключами симметричного шифрования которым потом шифруется поток

Comment: *В сети пишут* -- пожалуйста, никогда так не пишите. Либо прикладывайте прямую ссылку ("В этой статье пишут"), либо не ссылайтесь вовсе. Эта штука не имеет к HTTPS никакого отношения, это решение известной задачки на сообразительность о передаче посылки по ненадёжному каналу при отсутствии у адресата ключа.

Comment: Вот есть отличная статья с картинками без мудрёных речевых оборотов https://habrahabr.ru/post/188042/ . Вот например такая картинка много проясняет https://habrastorage.org/getpro/habr/post_images/4c3/1e6/ee3/4c31e6ee30dc899a30c070ee68cde177.jpg

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Почему при шифровании TLS используются именно простые числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739996/23044)

Comment: объяснение с [красками принципа DH обмена ключей](https://youtu.be/YEBfamv-_do?t=2m40s)

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS это HTTP поверх TLS. В TLS используется протокол Диффи-Хеллмана для обмена ключами, про который вы и спрашивали.
https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS
Сертификаты используются для установления сеансового ключа симметричного шифрования. При установлении сеансового ключа используется асимметричное шифрование в протоколе диффи-хеллмана с проверкой подлинности сообщений с использованием сертификата сервера.

Comment: Не всегда при помощи сертификатов устанавливаются ключи, так же как и использование диффи-хелмана. Это зависит от выбранного набора шифров.

Comment: @Zergatul Ты говоришь про `TLS_DH_anon`, `TLS_PSK` и `DH_SRP`? От [набора](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Key_exchange_or_key_agreement) [алгоритмов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D1.8B.2C_.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D1.83.D1.8E.D1.89.D0.B8.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.8F_.D0.B2_TLS).

Comment: Даже в самых распространенных по типу `TLS_DHE_RSA` сертификат используется только для подписи, фактически никак не влияя на установление сеансового ключа.