# Почему при шифровании TLS используются именно простые числа?

Tags: алгоритм, безопасность, ssl, шифрование, криптография

Почему при шифровании TLS, да и вообще в криптографии используются именно простые числа? Почему бы не использовать любые?

Comment: математика того требует :) Всякие там теоремы Ферма и иже с ними...

Comment: А конкретнее можно ,т.к. сообщение не информативно?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, мне кажется вы скорее сможете получить информативный ответ на каком-нибудь форуме по математике. Только учтите, понять его может быть сложно, поскольку большинство математиков будут объяснять его, считая, что вы владеете математикой в той же степени, что и они

Comment: Зачем вы даёте бессмысленные ответы, ссылки на сайты (в данном случае Википедия), в которых нет ответа на конкретный вопрос, вы ведёте себя как очередной тролль коих на этом сайте и так очень много развелось. Если решили отвечать на вопросы, освойте как правильно отвечать на вопросы, можете как раз для этого использовать поисковые навыки

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, ОК, не буду давать "бессмысленные ответы" - удачи вам в ваших нелегких поисках ;-)

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, когда отвечаете кому-то в комментариях используйте `@nick` для понятности

Comment: @MaxU    Разумное решение

Comment: связанный вопрос https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/32415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна причина в том, что *легко умножить 2 большие простые числа*, например

```
393050634124102232869567034555427371542904833 * 170141183460469231731687303715884105727
```

дает сразу

```
66874100049762646240147492397977579549553083399872470020691839934725993584071278591
```

(`Python`, < 0.2 секунд), no обратное сделать (разложить большое число на простые числа) *практически не возможно* - нет общего достаточно быстрого алгоритма (см.  [Алгоритмы факторизации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D0.A4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0).)

Вообще это работа *на несколько лет* даже для *супер компьютеров*.

Comment: А что, если я перемножу 2 больших непростых числа? например 393050634124102232869567034555427371542904834 * 170141183460469231731687303715884105728

Comment: Какой вы ожидаете увидеть здесь ответ? За всем этим стоит очень сложная математическая теория. Вы думаете, вам здесь кто-то в ответе на 5 строчек объяснит эту все теорию, и вам сразу станет все понятно? Так не бывает. Невозможно объяснить человеку, который не умеет умножать числа, что такое интеграл и производная, и зачем они нужны.

Comment: Я умею умножать числа, знаю, что такое интеграл и производные.  Был задан конкретный вопрос, почему при шифровании TLS используются именно простые числа? Если не знаете или не хотите отвечать, или просто не умеете правильно отвечать, можете не писать бессмысленные комментарии. Правильно ответить на вопрос, это пояснить на конкретном примере, чтобы было явно видно, в чем преимущество простых чисел в шифровании? Кстати, для этого не нужно знать про интегралы и производные

Comment: Разложение будет состоять с *более чем 2* простых чисел.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, если вы перемножаете два простых числа, то обратная операция даст так же только эти два числа. Если вы перемножаете два "непростых" числа, то обратная операция уже дает не один вариант.

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, как раз по произведению непростых чисел вы не сможете однозначно узнать какие числа были перемножены (это следует из определения простых чисел). Например - как можно __однозначно__ указать произведение каких двух чисел дает `24`. А для числа 21 - это делается простой факторизацией. Так вот как раз факторизирование огромных чисел очень трудоемкая операция.

Comment: Смотрите, `120 = 2 * 60 = 3 * 20 = 4 * 15 = 5 * 24 = 6 * 20 = 8 * 15  = 10 * 12`. Когда я даю вам число `120`, вы узнаете, какие 2 числа я перемножил? Но когда я даю вам например число `77`, это совсем другое.

Comment: @минусовавший, было бы неплохо пояснить почему данный ответ заминусовали...

Comment: @MarianD, советую вам вместо "в цикле пробовать все приемлемые возможности" указать ссылку на [Факторизация целых чисел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4_.D1.84.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8_.D0.A4.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0)

Comment: @MaxU спасибо вам, я использовал ваш хороший совет.

Comment: С удовольствием объясню минус. Из вашего ответа неосведомленному человеку невозможно понять, а каким же образом эти числа вообще используются при (де)шифрации и следовательно упоминание *сложности факторизации* ничего не проясняет.  (добавьте, хотя бы `Для шифрования используется операция возведения в степень по модулю большого числа. Для дешифрования (обратной операции) за разумное время необходимо уметь вычислять функцию Эйлера от данного большого числа, для чего необходимо знать разложение числа на простые множители.` из описания RSA)

Comment: Так-то все понятно, но я вот о чем подумал. Если мы используем простое число, перехвативший сообщение по идее может использовать тот факт, что используются простые числа и оперировать только с ними, перемножать только их (коих намного меньше всех натуральных чисел). Тогда получается не полный перебор, а перебор только простых чисел. Может оно то на то и выходит, если бы использовались все числа (в несколько раз больше попаданий, но зато нужен полный перебор)

Comment: Смотрите, `27644437` - большое число (простое). Но число `27644437 + 1 = 27644436` уже 'не так большое' - вы сразу можете видеть что оно делимое на `4` и `9` и вы получите вместо большого числа 3 маленькие (`27644436 = 4 * 9 * 767901`) - и вы можете даже продолжать и видеть что последнее делимое опять на `3` и `23` и получить еще меньшее числа.

Comment: Да это понятно, я имею ввиду другое. На простом примере, если разложить на множители непростое число 60 (6*10, 3*20, 12*5, 4*15) - по сути 4 варианта подходящие. И простое число 57 (3*19) - всего один вариант и сразу подходящий (с первой попытки взломщик гипотетически его бы определил). Вроде бы в 4 раза сложнее подобрать, но имея библиотеку простых чисел, взломщики же будут оперировать только с простыми числами коих меньше нежели непростых (т.е. и перебирать нужно будет намного меньше). А если использовались бы все числа - в случае простых вероятность попадания выше, но и перебора больше.

Comment: @MarianD, encrypted: 57243947902368893167773813031480887420405473470581916927787727485808373418222475418

Answer (score 9):

TLS допускает использование различных протоколов шифрования и обмена ключей. Разные протоколы используют простые числа по совершенно различным причинам:

## RSA

Один из самых популярных протоколов шифрования, RSA, основывается на том, что задача [факторизации числа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) - разложение *составного* числа на простые множители (скорее всего), не разрешима с полиномиальной сложностью на обычных компьютерах (но [разрешима за полиномиальное время на квантовых, криптоапокалипсис грядет](https://habrahabr.ru/post/188846/)).

Т.е. если у вас есть два огромных простых числа *p* и *q*, то тот, кто знает только *n = p* * *q*, проведет достаточно много времени, пытаясь разложить *n* обратно на *p* и *q*. Естественно, есть оговорки, позволяющие отсечь известные субэкспоненциальные алгоритмы, например, *p* и *q* должны отличатся порядком хотя бы на пару разрядов, но в общем случае можно считать что большие *p* и *q* сделают решение задачи факторизации *n* дико долгим.

При этом, найти два больших простых числа - достаточно легко.

Так что использование больших простых чисел - это способ получить огромное и тяжело факторизируемое составное число.

---

RSA описывает подбор/генерацию чисел e, d, n, таких, что для любого значения *m* будет справедливо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Способ генерации предполагает выбор *n = p* * *q*, *e* = *65,537* (или любому другому небольшому числу). Т.е. они находятся быстро. Пара *(n, e)* - это публичный ключ.

Доказано, что если взять в качесте *d* результат решения уравнения *ed = 1(mod ϕ(n))*, то тройка *(e, d, n)* будет отвечать требованию выше.

*ϕ(n)* - [это функция Эйлера](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%AD%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B2_RSA) - равная количеству натуральных чисел, меньших *n* и взаимно простых с ним. Для ее нахождения нужно факторизовать *n*. Т.е. если вы знаете только *(n, e)*, то поиск *d* решением этого уравнения займет вечность.

Но при этом *φ(p) = p − 1*, *φ(q) = q − 1*. И для простых *p* и *q*:

*φ(n)* = *φ(pq)* = *(p − 1)* * *(q − 1)*.

Так что вы берете два больших простых числа, быстро вычисляете *φ(n)* и *n*, получаете *d* из уравнения выше. Простые числа и *φ(n)* выбрасываете и никому не показываете. *(n, d)* - это ваш приватный ключ, и узнать его, зная только *(n, e)*, ни у кого не получится за разумное время.

После этого любой, у кого есть ваш публичный ключ может зашифровать для вас сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот расшифровать его можете только вы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Из взаимозаменяемости e и d и одинаковости для шагов для шифрации/дешифрации следует второй способ применения RSA - *только вы* можете зашифровать известный текст так, что расшифровать его можно будет только с помощью публичного ключа.

Если вы допишете к концу сообщения его чексумму, зашифрованную *приватным ключом* (получив при этом "электронную подпись"), то любой может посчитать ту же чексумму, "расшифровать" подпись, и сравнить два значения. Если они совпадут - значит сообщение дошло без изменений, и отправили его именно вы.

---

## Diffie-Hellman

Протокол обмена ключами DH полагается не на сложность факторизации, а на [сложность решения задачи дискретного логарифмирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Он основан на том, что нельзя быстро вычислить ключ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

зная только *g<sup>a</sup>*, *g<sup>b</sup>*, *g* и *p*.

Но при этом он легко позволяет сторонам вычислить этот общий ключ, [переслав по открытому каналу *g<sup>a</sup>*, *g<sup>b</sup>*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BF.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.80.D0.B0.D1.84.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B9.D0.BA.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C), если одна сторона придумает свое секретное *a*, а вторая - свое секретное *b*.

## Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman

Даже [основы эллиптической криптографии](https://habrahabr.ru/post/188958/) в один пост SO не влезут, так что стоит только упомянуть, что [ECDHE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.90.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3_.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D0.BA.D0.BB.D1.8E.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.BC.D0.B8_.D0.BF.D0.BE_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D1.83_.D0.94.D0.B8.D1.84.D1.84.D0.B8-.D0.A5.D0.B5.D0.BB.D0.BB.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B0) так же полагается не на сложность факторизации, а на [сложность решения задачи дискретного логарифмирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Для задачи дискретного логарифмирования есть субэкспоненциальный алгоритм Полига-Хеллмана, позволяющий свести решение проблемы для n точек к подзадачам для множителей n - p<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>2</sub>, p<sub>3</sub>, p<sub>4</sub>. Соответственно, количество точек кривой выбирают таким, чтобы оно делилось на какое-то большое простое число *p*, сравнимое по длине с *n*. Т.е. простые числа в ECDHE используются только косвенно, в качестве "ограничителя простоты". Из этих же соображений значения *p*, *g* в DH [накладываются соответствующие ограничения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%A5%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.9E.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D0.B0.5B2.5D).

Comment: стоит заметить, что вопрос не является чисто теоретическим (вот [commit, который в DH составной p в socat добавляет](http://repo.or.cz/socat.git/commitdiff/281d1bd6515c2f0f8984fc168fb3d3b91c20bdc0)). Составные числа на месте простых можно использовать в качестве [NOBUS] backdoor. [How does a non-prime modulus for Diffie-Hellman allow for a backdoor?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/32415/43422).

Comment: Паш, ну твой ответ также не блещет простотой - тоже отсылка к загадочной суперматематике, так что мы квиты

Comment: @Barmaley он и не должен блистать простотой :) но вся суперматематика в нем ограничивается основами теории чисел. Это обычно преподают вместе с теорией графов и операциями над матрицами, примерно на 2-м курсе любого *хорошего* универа.

Answer (score 5):

На самом деле ничего суперсложного здесь нет.

1) TLS базируется на асимметричной криптографии, в каковой есть понятие приватного и публичного ключей

2) Если не вдаваться в математические тонкости асимметричной криптографии, навроде теоремы Эйлера, Ферма, Галуа и проч. мастодонтов то эти ключи (например, в алгоритме RSA) вычисляется на основе целых числе `p, q` (необязательно кстати и простых):

```
PublicKey={e(p,q), p*q} //e(p,q) - некая целочисленная функция (публичная экспонента)
PrivateKey={d(p,q), p*q) //d(p,q) - также некая целочисленная функция (приватная экспонента)
```

грубо говоря, если знать эти 2 числа `p, q` то можно вычислить ключи. Теперь внимание, атакующему всегда известно их произведение `p*q` - из публичного ключа, который как явствует из его названия известен всем.

3) То есть чтобы дешифровать надо просто разложить некое число `n` на 2 множителя `p, q`. Задача называется [факторизацией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) - алгоритмов масса, но в целом все очень печально (с точки зрения скорости).

4) Подходим к самому главному - ради чего весь цирк с конями и затевался: зачем требуется, чтобы `p, q` были простыми? Здесь есть 2 ответа:

1. Функции `e(p, q)` и `d(p, q)` - работают не со всеми числами, то есть если подать им на вход непростое число, то функции могут не дать ничего. Зато если `p, q` простые то функции работают безупречно.
2. Для усложнения факторизации `n`: разложение большого числа на простые сомножители усложняется с ростом длины числа как `n*log(n)`, то есть вы раскладываете 1024 битовое число, то сложность грубо говоря будет `1024*2^1024`, но если число вдруг окажется четным то его сложность составит уже `512*2^1023` - то есть вычислительная сложность упадет в 4 раза - соответственно простота гарантирует увеличение вычислительной сложности.

Comment: Если сократить ответ - то получится "используются простые числа....есть какие-то функции, e(p, q) и d(p, q), которые безупречно работают только с простыми числами, ". Т.е. **используются простые числа потому что на составных шифрование может не работать**. Отлично обоснованный ответ, но по сути - не намного информативнее "математика того требует" из комментариев к вопросу :)

Comment: А точно ли будет усложнение факторизации, ведь если разложить на множители непростое число для примера 60 (6*10, 3*20, 12*5, 4*15) - по сути 4 варианта подходящие. И простое число 57 (3*19) - всего один вариант и сразу подходящий (с первой попытки взломщик гипотетически его бы определил). Вроде бы в 4 раза сложнее подобрать, но имея библиотеку простых чисел, взломщики же будут оперировать только с простыми числами коих меньше нежели непростых (т.е. и перебирать нужно будет намного меньше). А если использовались бы все числа - в случае простых вероятность попадания выше, но и перебора больше

Answer (score 1):

Кажется разобрался с этой темой. На примере Диффи-Хеллмана. Чтобы найти ключ K, нужно решить уравнение K=g^a*b mod p, где "g", "p" - известно. Произведение простых чисел (очень больших) действительно сложно подобрать. И нужно использовать именно простые числа потому что нет базы данных среди больших простых чисел (а базы данных нет потому что нереально перебрать такие большие цифры), иначе бы это сильно ускорило решение задачи, как и со всеми числами. Но это в теории, а на практике серьезные взломщики вряд ли будут перебирать произведение 2-ух простых чисел. Т.к. чтобы найти секретный ключ K, можно решить и другое уравнение, которое тоже равно секретному ключу. K=B^a mod p, где "p" известно, а "B" можно перехватить (т.к. эта информация в незащищенном видео передается по сети). И тогда уже останется подобрать только "a". А если учесть, что "a" - как минимум нечетное и огромное (порядка 10^100) - отбросить на конце четные и диапазон слишком маленьких чисел. Хотя даже при всем при этом "a" замучаешься подбирать)

Answer (score 0):

В TLS для генерации ключей чаще всего используется криптоалгоритм [RSA](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA). В его основе лежит предположение, что [факторизация](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB) произведения простых чисел является вычислительно сложной операцией.

Легко умножить два простых числа, но очень сложно имея только произведение получить исходные числа. На сегоднешний день не существует эффективного алгоритма, который позволяет это сделать быстро.

Comment: Неправильно говорить, что в TLS используется RSA. Он может использоваться, а может и не использоваться. Может использоваться для генерации ключей, а может и для подписи.